# App keeps crashing and not running when testing ir

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, apk

I'm building an app and when I try to test it on an emulator its says unfortunately app has stopped so when I run it I get this errors from the logcat section,the app is static and contain contents without firebase or onesignal, and I run it on DroidX(Android 4.4.4,API 17)

Here is the error I get:

07-30 05:25:40.650 3188-3188/com.med E/Trace: error opening trace file: 
    No such file or directory (2)
    07-30 05:25:40.806 3188-3188/com.med E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 
    'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method 
     com.google.android.gms.common.wrappers.PackageManagerWrapper.zzb
      07-30 05:25:41.410 3188-3188/com.med E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
    ComponentInfo{com.med/com.med.Splash}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at 
   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2204)
        at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2254)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at 
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5069)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at 
         com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a 
   Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at 
 androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:686)
        at 
 androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:649)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:542)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.med.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:27)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1092)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2254) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5069) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name="com.med.Splash">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.med.MainActivity"></activity>
meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
android:value="ca-app-pub-"/>
</application>

<?xml version="1.0"?>










-<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->



-<style parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" name="AppTheme">

<!-- Customize your theme here. -->


<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

</resources>






package com.medi;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import com.google.ads.consent.*;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView play,play2,play3,play4,play5,play6,play7,play8,pause,pause2,pause3,pause4,pause5,pause6,pause7,pause8;

InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
MediaPlayer mPlayer;

private ConsentForm form;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] publisherIds = {"pub-3281091428733026"};

    ConsentInformation consentInformation = 
ConsentInformation.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(publisherIds, new 
ConsentInfoUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConsentInfoUpdated(ConsentStatus consentStatus) {
            // User's consent status successfully updated.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo(String errorDescription) {
            // User's consent status failed to update.
        }
    });

    URL privacyUrl = null;
    try {
        // TODO: Replace with your app's privacy policy URL.
        privacyUrl = new URL("");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Handle error.
    }
    form = new ConsentForm.Builder(getApplicationContext(), privacyUrl)
            .withListener(new ConsentFormListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentFormLoaded() {
                    // Consent form loaded successfully.
                    form.show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormOpened() {
                    // Consent form was displayed.
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormClosed(
                        ConsentStatus consentStatus, Boolean userPrefersAdFree) {
                    // Consent form was closed.
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormError(String errorDescription) {
                    // Consent form error.
                }
            })
            .withPersonalizedAdsOption()
            .withNonPersonalizedAdsOption()
            .withAdFreeOption()
            .build();

    form.load();

    play=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play);
    play2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play2);
    play3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play3);
    play4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play4);
    play5=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play5);
    play6=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play6);
    play7=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play7);
    play8=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play8);
    pause=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pause);
    pause2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pause2);
    pause3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pause3);
    pause4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pause4);
    pause5=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pause5);
    pause6=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pause6);
    pause7=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pause7);
    pause8=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pause8);

    AdView mAdViewB = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdViewB.loadAd(adRequest);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getApplicationContext());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.intestital_ads));
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    });

    requestNewInterstitial();

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.one);
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    play2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            play2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pause2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.two);
            mPlayer.start();

        }
    });

    play3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            play3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pause3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.three);
            mPlayer.start();

        }
    });

    play4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            play4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pause4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.four);
            mPlayer.start();

        }
    });

    play5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            play5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pause5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.five);
            mPlayer.start();

        }
    });

    play6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            play6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pause6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.six);
            mPlayer.start();

        }
    });

    play7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            play7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pause7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.seven);
            mPlayer.start();

        }
    });

    play8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            play8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pause8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.eigth);
            mPlayer.start();

        }
    });

    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPlayer.stop();
        }
    });

    pause2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pause2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            play2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPlayer.stop();
        }
    });

    pause3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pause3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            play3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPlayer.stop();
        }
    });

    pause4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pause4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            play4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPlayer.stop();
        }
    });

    pause5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pause5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            play5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPlayer.stop();
        }
    });

    pause6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pause6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            play6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPlayer.stop();
        }
    });

    pause7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pause7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            play7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPlayer.stop();
        }
    });

    pause8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pause8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            play8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mPlayer.stop();
        }
    });



}

private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

}

```
package com.med;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;



public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {



InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    AdView mAdViewB = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdViewB.loadAd(adRequest);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getApplicationContext());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.intestital_ads));
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    });

    requestNewInterstitial();


    Thread thread=new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);


                Intent intent= new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();


            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
    thread.start();


}
private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

...'use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.'
The Activity needs an App Compatible theme declared in the manifest.
Add to activity declaration in manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.med.Splash">
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Add to styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work without setting the `parent` attribute, correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: You can use any App compatible theme or you can make your own and extend it using parent. Then you just have to link the style to your activity in the manifest.

Comment: Yes but this AppTheme.NoActionBar is just a name and its not extending any compatible theme.

Comment: I believe it is a compatible theme not 100% on which themes are App Compat, if its not working try something like:    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

Comment: Sorry @vasmos I am not the one who asked the question, I am just verifying if your answer is based on something I don't know. I just answered this question myself at the same time as you.

Comment: There is no theme specified in the <Activity > tags so I'm pretty sure the manifest would have to be updated as well

Comment: It is specified in application tag, please take a look at manifest file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197187/discussion-between-vasmos-and-zohaib-amir).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is given in the error log you posted:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to >start activity ComponentInfo{com.med/com.med.Splash}: >java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a >Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

You are using AppCompatActivity so you have to use an Appcompat theme as the parent theme.

Goto `styles.xml` file, there is a style tag with name `AppTheme`,
change its `parent` attribute to this theme or similar:

```
<style
name= "AppTheme"
parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
...
/>
```

Comment: @MoukrimTaha can you show me your `styles.xml` file?

Comment: -<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->



-<style parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" name="AppTheme">

<!-- Customize your theme here. -->


<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

</resources>

Comment: @MoukrimTaha Try putting this line in your Splash Activity tag: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` like this:
`<activity android:name="com.med.Splash"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
>`

Comment: @MoukrimTaha Also, please post the code of your `Splash` class by editing your question, it may be the problem is because of using the wrong context.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#ffc95c">
    <activity android:name=".Splash" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

Comment: @MoukrimTaha post thw java file **in your question** pls.

Comment: Ok I added mainactivity and splash

Comment: @MoukrimTaha `<activity android:name="com.med.Splash" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >` this line is for **Manifest** file not layout file.